# UITextField inside UITableView cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios, uitextfield

I have been reading through a lot of things trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I have been trying to add 4 UITextFields inside of UITableView cells. I have the UITextFields created through IB, as well as the UITableView. I add the textfields to a NSMutableArray and then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath I am adding these text field object in the array. into 4 cells. However, this is where my issues arise. The text fields are not lined up in the table (img: http://cl.ly/5a02f3acdd44d8a08125). Here is some code:

viewDidLoad:

    `textBoxList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

```
[textBoxList addObject: txtName];
[textBoxList addObject: txtIP];
[textBoxList addObject: txtPort];
[textBoxList addObject: txtPassword];
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] init] autorelease];
}

// Set up the cell...
[cell.contentView addSubview: [textBoxList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];


return cell;
```

}

Is this happening because I set these UITextFields up in IB and not creating them dynamically? Something with my delegates? Im lost....

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the frame of the labels relative to the cell.

Comment: Like this?  txtName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,30)];
 txtIP = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,30)];
 txtPassword = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,30)];
 txtPort = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,30)];

Comment: Well, you don't want to create all new labels if you already have them in a nib you loaded. Unless you're moving away from that strategy?

Comment: I am still using that strategy. Not sure how to set the frames on them though

Comment: Ok, well I'm not sure how much you really buy yourself by putting them in a nib (as opposed to just putting the strings in a .strings file). But, leaving that aside, 'frame' is a property of UIView. So txtName.frame = CGRectMake(...)